# Java Process.waitFor() not working as expected

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I'm attempting to launch an msi installer for mySQL from Java as follows:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process sqlInstaller = run.exec(
    "rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL msiexec /qb /i mysql-5.5.27-winx64.msi REBOOT=ReallySuppress");
sqlInstaller.waitFor();
System.out.println(sqlInstaller.exitValue());
```

The method is returning almost immediately with an exit value of 0 and continues execution. However, since the next part of my code proceeds to create some tables, I need to guarantee that mySQL installation has successfully completed.

Any ideas about how to achieve this, or about why `waitFor()` is behaving as it is, would be most welcome.

Comment: Follow the advice in the article linked from [runtime.exec info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).

Comment: `waitFor` behaves as expected. `rundll32` exits immediately after starting the installation process (with 0 exit code, if the process started successfully). Try to run `msiexec` instead of `rundll32`.

Comment: @khachik I'd say your comment qualifies for an answer.

Comment: [What's the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don't use it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx)